# how to CREATE and UPDATE VIEW in SQL Server 2008 using single query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two query. create new view and update view query.

1) vw_delay (new),

```
CREATE VIEW vw_delay AS
        SELECT ....
```

2) vw_RDoc (exist)

```
 ALTER VIEW vw_RDoc AS
        SELECT ....
```

I want to run both query as single query. I tried to run like this,

```
CREATE VIEW vw_delay AS
            SELECT ....
  ALTER VIEW vw_RDoc AS
            SELECT ....
```

but it returns this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vw_delay, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.
>
> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vw_delay, Line 7
>   'ALTER VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.

How to do this? Please help me.

Comment: Don't tag products which are not involved. I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: sorry for that @RahulTripathi and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is necessary to do is add GO after first CREATE VIEW.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_delay AS
            SELECT ....
GO
  ALTER VIEW vw_RDoc AS
            SELECT ....
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the GO after the Create View. Do remember that GO is used as a delimiter for the BATCHES

```
CREATE VIEW vw_delay AS
SELECT ....
GO
ALTER VIEW vw_RDoc AS
SELECT ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use batch terminator 'GO'. it will separate the both batches and then it will work fine

```
CREATE VIEW YourViewName AS
SELECT * FROM tablex

GO

ALTER VIEW YourViewName AS
SELECT * FROM tabley
```